# How to remove text written over top of FloatVectorProperty

Tags: scripting

I'm writing a panel that displays a vector that in meant to indicate the direction of a normal.  Using `FloatVectorProperty` with `subtype="DIRECTION"` would seem ideal for this, but the result has the property name written over top of the control.  Since the property name is already written above it, is there a way to remove this name from the control display?

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel


class NormalToolSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    normal : bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Normal", 
        description="Direction of normal in Fixed mode", 
        default = (1, 0, 0), 
        subtype="DIRECTION"
    )
    

class TestPanel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_test_panel"    
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"

    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        settings = scene.my_tool

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(settings, "normal")


bpy.utils.register_class(NormalToolSettings)
bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)

bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=NormalToolSettings)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Set the text of the layout**

If `text` argument is not set in layout functions, it defaults to the name of the property. Set it to "" to "remove".

```
    col.prop(settings, "normal", text="")
```

Note: will also take out the prop name written above. Can be replaced with

```
    col.label(text="Normal")
```